# VBA - applying function to a sub

Tags: vba

im a VBA newbie. I have to create function, that transform state address to state full name eg. CA -> California and apply it to the whole column with addresses.
Given task:

*Open VBE and add module named modFunction. In this module create function (named this function StateFullName) which transform state address into state full name. Function should take one parameter (state address) and return one string value (state full name)

In column 7 each rows with data should have full state name (Tip: use loop and function prepared in modFunction).*

I have created a function, but now I don't know how to apply it in sub with loop.

My function:

```
Function StateFullName(state_address As String) As String

    Select Case state_address
        Case "CA": StateFullName = "California"
        Case "AZ": StateFullName = "Arizona"
        Case "MT": StateFullName = "Montana"
        Case "NM": StateFullName = "New Mexico"
    End Select
    
End Function
```

Comment: on any other script you do, `state = StateFullName("CA")`. May also want to make this one a `Public Function`

Comment: Sounds like homework to me.

Comment: It sounds like this is supposed to be a UDF (User Defined Function) for use in a cell on the worksheet. If that's the case, then @RicardoA advice to make it a `Public` function is spot on. If the function is NOT a UDF, then you'll have to create a `Sub` and create a loop that calls the `StateFullName` function for each abbreviation and puts the value into a row in column 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting up your Function as a public function, you can use it in two ways, as a formula and as a Function on other Macros/Subscripts.

Here is a sample of your code:

```
Public Function statestring(twoletter As String) As String
    Select Case twoletter
        Case "CA": statestring = "California"
        Case "AZ": statestring = "Arizona"
        Case Else: statestring = "Unknown State"
    End Select
End Function
```

And here I am using it as a Formula on Column B, top right you can see the formula:

[image]

And here I am using it on another Sub as a Function to fill Column C:

(It could be a lot better coded but I just wrote it as it came to mind)

Edit: After a quick thought an offset would be make it much better

```
Sub getFullState()
    Set wk = ThisWorkbook
    With wk.Sheets("Sheet1")
        'startRow = 2 ' Removed
        For Each Rng In .Range("A2:A4")
            'Next line Replaced with Offset
            '.Range("C" & startRow).Value = statestring(Rng.Value)
            Rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = statestring(Rng.Value)
            'startRow = startRow + 1 'Removed
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your effort! I get it know. Cheers!

Comment: Np, glad I could help. If this answered your question please mark it as answered, if not please let me know and I will try to make sure it does.